# Removing Worker node from running Spark Job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to see if there is a way to gracefully remove a worker node from the Spark cluster during the run. For example, a way to tell the scheduler not to assign new tasks to a worker so I can delete it after the current work is done. 
Any IDEA?